# ¿Cómo mostrar spinner o "cargando..." al navegar entre vistas?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una aplicación web con el típico "Admin template", el menú lateral con las opciones y el contenido. El menú está definido en una vista parcial que se carga en el layout.

Algunas de las vistas a las que se navega tardan en cargar, y quiero mostrar algún tipo de mensaje (spinner, texto o lo que sea) al usuario para que vea que está "trabajando" y no se ha colgado.

La idea sería que al pulsar en el menú se mostrara el mensaje bloqueando la pantalla y al terminar de cargarse la vista dicho mensaje desapareciera.

He visto algún ejemplo y el mostrarlo al pulsar en una opción de menú creo que sabría como hacerlo, pero ¿cómo hago para que desaparezca una vez se ha cargado la vista?

*Añado más información a mi pregunta, a ver si me explico mejor...*

En la vista parcial del menú que cargo en el layout tengo algo así:

```
 <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { action = "Nuevo", controller = "Producto" })" class="sidenav-link"><div>Nuevo producto</div></a>
```

y en la vista de nuevo producto he puesto estos alerts de js.

```
 $(function () {
    alert('Evento ready');
 });

 $(window).on('load', function (e) {
    alert('Evento load');
 });
```

La secuencia ahora mismo es la siguiente estando en el menú principal y visualizando la vista dashboard:
1. Click en la opción de menú 'Nuevo producto'.
2. **Un tiempo de espera de unos 15seg.** mientras se sigue viendo la vista dashboard.
3. Se muestra el alert 'Evento ready'.
4. Se muestra el alert 'Evento load'.

Lo que yo quiero es que el "cargando...' se muestre nada más hacer click en la opción del menú (paso 1) y se esté visualizando hasta el 'Evento load'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder mostrar un `spinner` cuando se navega deberas cambiar la forma en como cargas las vistas, ya no podra ser un link desde el menu, sino que deberas invocar el action que retorna la view usando `ajax` para depsues inyectar este en el lugar que corresponda al `body` de la pagina (por lo general definido con un `div`)

[How To Load Partial Views In ASP.NET MVC Using jQuery Ajax](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d551d3/how-to-load-partial-views-in-Asp-Net-mvc-using-jquery-ajax/)

[Return Partial View from Controller using AJAX in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Return-Partial-View-from-Controller-using-AJAX-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

Usarias algo como ser

```
$("#linkmenu").click(function () {

    spinner.show();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("controller", "action")',
        data: '',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {
            $('#divContent').html(response);
            spinner.hide();
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });

});
```

veras como justo ante de invocar el action muestras el spinner y en el `success` de la llamada `ajax` lo ocultas

Comment: Leandro, y ¿cómo quedaría entonces la sustitución de la etiqueta del enlace?

Comment: La opcion del menu deberia ejecutar un evento click en javascript o jquery, es alli donde realizas el $.ajax y cargas el html que retorna. Esto te qudaria mucho mas faci si usaras alguna libreria como ser AngulerJs ya que permite desarrollos SPA (Simple Page Application)

Answer (score 0):

si estás usando jquery el evento que te dice si tu web terminó de cargar es window load

cuando ya se ha cargado la web por completo ocultas tu spinner

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.spinner').addClass('hide')
})
```

Comment: memoadian, el evento está bien para usarlo, pero no es solución por si solo. He añadido información adicional a mi pregunta.